# mkinitrd to preload virtualBox LSI SAS storage drivers

Tags: linux, redhat, virtualbox, initramfs

I am trying to compile my own kernel (2.6.9).
Everything works on the compilation and building end, but...

After rebooting to the new kernel - the LVM (VolumeGroup00) cannot be loaded.

My suspicious is that the mkinitrd does not pre-load the relevant drivers for the LSI SAS storage which VirtualBox has.

I'm using RHel for the process.

Does somebody have an idea what parameters I need to add to the mkinitrd to make it load the right drivers?

I tried to add "--preload mptbase --preload mptscsih " - both didn't help.

I would appreciate if you can also mention the driver I should add to the .config (I added the "general" ones, I am not sure if it's enough)

Thanks

---

I'll be more concrete:

After running mkinitrd (with any combination of parameters I thought about)

The output is:

```
Uncompressing Linux... Ok, booting the kernel.
audit(1410035747.4294966701:0): initialized
Red Hat nash version 4.2.1.6 starting
  Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
  No volume groups found
  Unable to find volume group "VolGroup00"
ERROR: /bin/lvm exited abnormally! (pid 202)
mount: error 6 mounting ext3
mount: error 2 mounting none
switchroot: mount failed: 22
umount /initrd/dev failed: 2
kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as expected the problem is missing drivers.

There are multiple drivers that can cause it.

In my case - the VirtualBox with SCSI HardDrive should have the following drivers set:

1. Device Drivers -> Block Device -> Initial RAM disk (initrd) Support
2. Device Drivers -> Block Device -> RAM disk support
3. Device Drivers -> SCSI device support -> SCSI device support
4. Device Drivers -> SCSI device support -> SCSI disk support
5. Device Drivers -> Fusion MPT device support -> Fusion MPT (base + ScsiHost) drivers

Note that these are the ONLY drivers required for the storage (in my case the Fusion MPT was missing and affected the boot).

If you want to run network / use keyboard other device drivers are necessary, but the system on a VirtualBox would boot with these device driver only (but without graphics / terminal / keyboard would not be usable / look as if it is stuck).